# scanf считывает перевод каретки

Tags: c++, c

Вообщем мне нужно ввести длину строки числом. После ввода цифры и нажатия enter перевод каретки ('\n') уходит в функцию. Так вот, как мне сделать так, чтобы scanf считал только число?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

char* GetLine(int len){
  char* text = NULL;
  char ch;
  for(int counter = 1 ;; counter++){
    ch = getchar();
    text = (char*)realloc(text,counter*sizeof(char));
    if((ch != '\n')&&(counter != (len+1))){
      *(text+counter-1) = ch;
    }
    else{
      *(text+counter-1) = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
  return text;
}





int main(){
  // Disable stdout buffering
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  char* sep;
  sep = GetLine(-1);
  /*for(int i = 0; *(sep+i) != '\0'; i++){
    printf("%c",*(sep+i));
  }*/
  // printf("\n");

  int* len;
  len = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("Введите длину текста:\n");
  scanf("%d",len);
  printf("Длина текста: %d\n",*len);
  char* message;
  message = GetLine(*len);



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Если  `'\n'` "уходит в функцию", то это как раз и говорит именно то том, что `scanf("%d"...` считывает только число. Как и должно быть. Так что же именно вам нужно? В чем проблема?

Comment: Немного некорректно задал вопрос, извиняюсь. Вообщем, как сделать так, чтобы после ввода числа мы избавились от '\n'?

Comment: @ReCursia Вы уже избавились. `scanf` прочитала данные ***после*** нажатия `Enter`, "проглотив" `\n`, после чего распарсила введённые данные и поместила их в переменную `len`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду, что `'\n'` осталась в буфере?
Просто считайте и проигнорируйте из буфера все до `'\n'` включительно - например,

```
scanf("%*[^\n]s%*c");
```

или можно использовать `fgets(stdin)` в какой-нибудь буфер. Или цикл

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Таким методом вы удаляете все, что оставалось от введенной строки, так что если ввели что-то типа `45 18` и потом собирались считать второе число - то так поступать не надо :)